# Ec2 instance IP address changed to new ip address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip, instance

My ec2 ipv4 public ip address changes to new ip address automatically and now when I login it says in console

```
 POST http://13.211.13.11:8080/login net::ERR_TIMED_OUT then (async)        
(anonymous) @   login.js:5
(anonymous) @   login.js:3
(anonymous) @   loginpage.js:48
(anonymous) @   loginpage.js:37
Show 31 more frames
```

I changed my util.js in client folder to refer to new ip address however its still referring to old ip address and hence I can't login. is there any way to fix this so I can login to my website rather getting the error it can't find old ip address?

I am using amazon ec2 instance and rds for this application

Comment: It is rather strange to have that information appear when you login. How are you connecting? Are you using SSH to login? Or are you saying that you are connecting to the instance via a web browser and logging in? Or are you performing a POST from an app as a login request? If it is a response from a web app, then you should login to the instance (eg via SSH) and update your code.

Comment: I am connecting ec2 instance via web browser and the issue is now that ip address is changed and when i go to that new ip address website and try to login it says in error it can't find old ip address and hence I can't login. SO any way or where should I change to website to look for new ip address rather old?

Comment: It's your code, so only you would know.

Answer (score 0):

The Public IP address assigned to an Amazon EC2 instance will change if the instance is Stopped and Started.

To keep a consistent public IP address, create an **Elastic IP address** and assign it to the instance. This is a **static IP address** that will stay with the instance until you dissociate it.

Comment: I am connecting ec2 instance via web browser and the issue is now that ip address is changed and when i go to that new ip address website and try to login it says in error it can't find old ip address (hence server error) and hence I can't login. SO any way or where should I change so that website  look for new ip address rather old when I click on login button? or could it be database RDS is still pointing to old ip address and hence I can't login